# In the AES spec (FIPS 197) why is InvCipher not the same as Cipher backwards?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography, aes, specifications

In the AES Spec ([FIPS 197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf)) the pseudo code for the AES encryption routine (called Cipher, pg 15 Fig. 5) which is as follows:

```
Cipher(byte in[4*Nb], byte out[4*Nb], word w[Nb*(Nr+1)])
begin
     byte  state[4,Nb]
     state = in
     AddRoundKey(state, w[0, Nb-1]) 
     for round = 1 step 1 to Nr–1
        SubBytes(state) 
        ShiftRows(state) 
        MixColumns(state) 
        AddRoundKey(state, w[round*Nb, (round+1)*Nb-1])
    end for
    SubBytes(state)
    ShiftRows(state)
    AddRoundKey(state, w[Nr*Nb, (Nr+1)*Nb-1])
    out = state
end
```

To decrypt, the specification says that you can simply undo all of the steps in Cipher, that is apply the inverse operations in reverse order to the way they are performed in the encryption.

As in:

```
Decrypt(byte in[4*Nb], byte out[4*Nb], word w[Nb*(Nr+1)])
begin
     byte  state[4,Nb]
     state = in

     AddRoundKey(state, roundkey[10])
     invShiftRows(state)
     invSubBytes(state)

     for round = 9 step 1 to 1
        AddRoundKey(state, roundkey[round])
        invMixColumns(state)
        invShiftRows(state)
        invSubBytes(state)  
    end for

    AddRoundKey(state, roundkey[0]) 

    out = state
end
```

Where roundkey[x] is the roundkey used in that round of the encryption.

However, this does not match the pseudo-code given for the inverse cipher in the spec which is instead:

```
InvCipher(byte in[4*Nb], byte out[4*Nb], word w[Nb*(Nr+1)])
begin
    byte  state[4,Nb]
    state = in
    AddRoundKey(state, w[Nr*Nb, (Nr+1)*Nb-1]) // See Sec. 5.1.4
    for round = Nr-1 step -1 downto 1
        InvShiftRows(state) 
        InvSubBytes(state) 
        AddRoundKey(state, w[round*Nb, (round+1)*Nb-1])
        InvMixColumns(state) 
    end for
    InvShiftRows(state)
    InvSubBytes(state)
    AddRoundKey(state, w[0, Nb-1])
    out = state
end
```

So my question is, how is the presented inverse (Figure 12. pg 21) equivalent to the 'straight undo' such that it still works and how is it better than the 'straight undo' method for decrypting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into the details of Nr*Nb, (Nr+1)*Nb-1, etc., the two sequences look the same to me. Let's say you only had two round loops. Here is your sequence side-by-side with the spec's sequence:

```
AddRoundKey      AddRoundKey
invShiftRows
invSubBytes      InvShiftRows
                 InvSubBytes
AddRoundKey      AddRoundKey
invMixColumns    InvMixColumns
invShiftRows
invSubBytes      InvShiftRows
                 InvSubBytes
AddRoundKey      AddRoundKey
invMixColumns    InvMixColumns
invShiftRows
invSubBytes      InvShiftRows
                 InvSubBytes
AddRoundKey      AddRoundKey
```

Everything is in the same order -- it should produce the same results. I can't say that one way is better than the other. (Well, other than yours is easier to read.)